# Every point of a perfect set in complete metric space is condensation point

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

here is the one of the answer my question in the cite but I would like to ask something,

'If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space, and $A$ is perfect and $x \in A$ it follows that for any $r>0$, $D(x,r) \cap A$ is non-empty (where $D(x,r) = \{y \in X: d(x,y) \le r\}$ is the closed ball of radius $r$ around $x$).

$D(x,r)$  is closed and hence so is $D(x,r) \cap A$ and thus also complete.

So if $D(x,r) \cap A$ were countable for some $r>0$, we must have an isolated point $a_0 \in D(x,r) \cap A$ (or we'd contradict the Baire property) and this can only happen if $A$ already had an isolated point, which is not the case. So all points of $A$ are condensation points.'

so in this solution every closed ball of radius $r$ is taken and intersection of that closed balls with A is uncountable, but can we conclude it $x$ is at the same time condensation point of the perfect set $A$? Because of the definition of condensation point is the one whose all OPEN neighbourhoods are uncountable , can we conclude from this solutıon every open ones uncountable? if so, can we say that $a_{0}$ is also isolated point of $A$ itself?

any hint would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B(x,r)$ be the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$. Clearly

$$D\left(x,\frac{r}2\right)\subseteq B(x,r)$$

for every $r>0$, so if some $B(x,r)$ were countable, $D\left(x,\frac{r}2\right)$ would also be countable, and $x$ would be an isolated point by the Baire category argument mentioned in the question.

Comment: can you please explain it a bit more? so $B(x,r)$ cannot be countable wee say? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Dans0804: That’s right: $B(x,r)$ cannot be countable, because that would make $D\left(x,\frac{r}2\right)$ countable, and we know that $D\left(x,\frac{r}2\right)$ can’t be countable.

Comment: so what about the isolated point? is there an $a_{0}$ as an isolated point or $x$ itself an isolated point? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Dans0804: $D\left(x,\frac{r}2\right)$ would be a countable Baire space.

Comment: thank you so much for the informations, was very helpful @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Dans0804: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I am so sorry for disturbing again sir, but I still could not get a contradiction, why $A$ must have an isolated point in this situation? can not see the contradiction for hours. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Dans0804: Suppose that $Y$ is a countable Baire space. If $Y$ has no isolated points, then $U_y=Y\setminus\{y\}$ is a dense open set for each $y\in Y$. $\{U_y:y\in Y\}$ is then a countable family of dense open sets, so its intersection is dense (because $Y$ is a Baire space). But its intersection is empty and is therefore **not** dense in $Y$. This contradiction shows that $Y$ must have an isolated point.

Comment: I exactly knew  that,  so $D(x,\frac{r}{2})\cap A$ must have isolated point, because it is countable,  let it be $x_{0}$ is isolated point of  $D(x,\frac{r}{2})\cap A$ does that mean also $A$ itself has  an isolated point ? If so, is that $x_{0}$ ? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Where is the contradiction actually, acırdın to solution, if $D(x,\frac{r}{2})\cap A$  Countable, it has isolated point, but what makes this point to $A$ for a contradiction ? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: If $x_{0}\in D(x,\frac{r}{2})\cap A$ isolated point , $x_{0}$ is isolated point of $A$? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Dans0804: If $x_0$ is isolated in $D\left(x,\frac{r}2\right)$, there is an open $U$ such that $U\cap D\left(x,\frac{r}2\right)=\{x_0\}$. Clearly we may assume that $U\subseteq B(x,r)$, so $x_0$ is isolated in $A\cap B(x,r)$ and hence in $A$.

Comment: Thanks much sir, for you patience too, appreciated:) @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Dans0804: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be a good idea to prove, first, the following fact:

"If a perfect set $A$ intersects a set $B$ in a point which is in the interior of $B$, then
such a point is not an isolated point of $B \cap A$."

With this fact in mind, notice that if $D(x,r) \cap A$ is a countable set then it has, necessarily,  a dense set of isolated points, isn't that so ? In particular, there would be an isolated point of $D(x,r) \cap A$ in $B(x,r) \cap A$.